# Why kernel quits when trying to FullSimplify Piecewise with default Nothing value?

Tags: kernel

I found that kernel of

```
    In[1]=$Version
(*"12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"*)
```

quits when trying to FullSimplify a simple piecewise function

```
Piecewise[{{0,  s == 0}}, Nothing]
FullSimplify[%]
(* kernel quit*)
```

Simple bug or invalid syntax?

Comment: I would not do it with the % the way you do it.  It will keep rerunning and if you have heaps of these in your code, that may be an explanation to your kernel quitting.  Try this instead FullSimplify[Piecewise[{{0, s == 0}}, Nothing]] which returns Nothing

Comment: The same behavior: kernel quit

Comment: OK in 12.2 on Windows 10: the code returns `\[Piecewise] 0 s==0
Nothing True

`.

Comment: Did you check that after printing the result kernel still is loaded?  Please enter something else to be sure that it is still here, since in 11.0 11.3, versions the kernel quits AFTER results are printed.

Comment: I also saw the kernel quit unexpectedly when executing the above code in MMA 12.0.0 on Win10-64. The `Piecewise` function works fine, although it is a bit odd, so I assume that something goes wrong inside `FullSimplify`. `Simplify` also leads to the same crash.

Comment: @MarcoB The original Piecewise was different. What you see is reduced input , i.e. "minimal example". It took some time to find what's going.

Comment: @user18792 But why do you need Nothing as the default value? That seems the crux of the problem. Perhaps if you could expand on that, somebody could come up with a workaround for you.

Comment: @MarcoB Suppose you write function, which returns set of solutions, which depend on symbolic parameters, something like f[s,S]:={Piecewise[f1,s^2-S^2>0],Piecewise[f2,s^2-S^2<0}. Now after you substitute numerical values for s,S, say s->1,S->2 one wants to get only a true set of solutions. And the most easy way to obtain it is by  setting default value of Piecewise to Nothing, since then it automatically disappears from the list. Of course workarounds exists, however this one is most elegant.